# Sizing in windows forms properties not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resize

I once created a windows forms app in Visual Studio 2017 using a 17-inch laptop, On downgrading to a 15 inch, the size of the build is small hence locking out some buttons, When I try resizing the form, it reverts to 1388/790, Does computer change affect program code? How can I manage to correct this?

Comment: Hi there, I think some code and some sample images would help clarify this. On the surface also, some of the language is a little confusing (e.g. the term 'build' here could mean the compiled executable or the machine itself).

Comment: By "Build" Imen compiled executable i.e debugging inside the sdk

Comment: @essythrees I Have found it to be an autoscaling by visual studio,

Comment: Try to set the form ``AutoScaleMode`` to ``Dpi``.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced similar when projecting the software from my pc using a projector.
I solved the problem by setting the AutoSize property of the window and panels to true.

```
// Form1
this.AutoSize = true;
```